# Access JPA <persistence-unit-metadata> programmatically

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

is it possible to access the information in `<persistence-unit-metadata>` through Java API?

```
<persistence-unit-metadata>
    <persistence-unit-defaults>
        <schema>MySchema</schema>
    </persistence-unit-defaults>
</persistence-unit-metadata>
```

I would like to read the schema "MySchema" via JPA API or EclipseLink API, which is the implementation I use.

Something like: entityManager.getDefaults().getSchema();
It's OK to cast or use any EclipseLink class, that's fine for this.

Thank you

Comment: What is it that you really want to achieve? What do you mean by "access the information"? You want to read the elements of your `orm.xml` file through JPA provider API or maybe you would like to read the database schema, tables, stored procedures, ... ?

Comment: I would like to access the default schema configured in the persistence-unit-defaults. Something like jpaConfig.getSchema(). I'd like to use JPA API or EclipseLink. But not access the XML directly, for instance through XPath, if possible at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After debugging for a while I found a solution to access the schema of an entity.

```
EntityType<MyEntity> entity = emf.getMetamodel().entity(MyEntity.class);

EntityTypeImpl entityTypeImpl = (EntityTypeImpl) entity;        
ClassDescriptor descriptor =  entityTypeImpl.getDescriptor();

String schema = descriptor.getDefaultTable().getTableQualifier();
```

Looking for an easier and better way to access the information! 
Thank you so much.

Comment: You can also use, em.unwrap(Session.class).getDescriptor(MyEntity.class).getDefaultTable().getTableQualifier();

Comment: Or to get the default qualifier on the Session, em.unwrap(Session.class).getLogin().getTabl‌​eQualifier();

Answer (score 1):

The previous replies didn't work for me. This is what I found to work:

```
String schema = em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class).getServerSession().getDescriptor(MyClass.class).getTables().get(0).getTableQualifier();
```

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here is a simpler way to get the table name:

`MyEntity.class.getAnnotation(javax.persistence.Entity.class).name();`

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old post, but worked for me with this

```
javax.persistence.Table table = MyEntity.class.getAnnotation(javax.persistence.Table.class)
```

from there you can get:

```
table.catalog()
table.indexes()
table.name()
table.schema()
table.uniqueConstraints()
```

Comment: forgot to add, JPA 2, Hibernate 5

Answer (score 0):

For database connections managed by Hibernate 6 the working solution I found was:

```java
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)entityManager
        .getEntityManagerFactory()
        .getProperties()
        .get("hibernate.connection.datasource");

    if (dataSource instanceof HikariDataSource hikariDataSource) {
        final String url = hikariDataSource.getJdbcUrl();
        // Parse the url according to your database engine ...
```