# Get DB schema name in JPA (from EntityManager/EntityManagerFactory)

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

In JPA (EclipseLink 2.4) I need to specify schema name in NativeQuery:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select foo from bar.table");
```

Above works but obviously I don't like hardcoding schema name, especially given the fact that I'm already specifying it in orm.xml:

```
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <schema>bar</schema>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>   
</entity-mappings>
```

Surely there must be a way to get schema name on runtime from somewhere?

Comment: A very similar question was asked here, with maybe not the ideal answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298058/access-jpa-persistence-unit-metadata-programmatically

Comment: Thanks. Although a bit awkward, the following seems to work: em.unwrap(Session.class).getLogin().getTabl‌​eQualifier()

Answer (score 2):

If using a persistence unit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="">
<persistence-unit name="MY_PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  ...................................
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://something:5432/MY_DB_NAME"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pass"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING"/>
</properties>
```

You can then use the EntityManagerFactory to extract the properties:

```
public String getDatabaseName() {
    String dbName = null;
    Map<String, Object> map = emf.getProperties();
    String url = (String) map.get("javax.persistence.jdbc.url");
    if(url != null) {
        dbName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    }
    return dbName;
}
```

where **emf** is the already created EntityManagerFactory.

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MY_PU");
```

Comment: P.S. This will not work for at least SQL Server, because jdbc url for it looks like: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbname