# retrieve database schema dynamically

Tags: java, database, jpa, eclipselink

I want to write a backup tool for my application and have to use JAVA 1.6. Inside my application are several databases like derby, mySQL .. Further there are different database schema names.

I´m using JPA and Eclipselink.

So far I wrote a method which creates a list of all tables with a specific schema name :

```
    private static List<String> getTableNames(String schema, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    final String TABLE_NAME = "TABLE_NAME";
    List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
    ResultSet tablesRS = dbmd.getTables(null, schema, null, null);
    while (tablesRS.next()) {
        tableNames.add(tablesRS.getString(TABLE_NAME));
    }

    return tableNames;
}
```

This works but I don´t know how I get the actualy schema name. I thought I can get the schema through the `EntityManager`. But I did not find any solution. Is there a way to get the schema name of my database through the `EntityManager`?
Is there a better way to dynamically retrieve the content of all tables which works with different databases?

Notice, that I must use Java 1.6.

I know there exists a method `getSchema()` inside a `connection` object since JAVA 1.7.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351308/get-db-schema-name-in-jpa-from-entitymanager-entitymanagerfactory)

Comment: the schema is not visible inside the `persistence.xml`, so I really need to get it via the `entity manager` or a `connection`.

Comment: some RDBMS don't support "schema". Most usages of JPA would likely not specify it, and hence get the default schema for a URL and/or username, hence you are outside the scope of JPA.

Comment: Your method is using the connection directly anyway and everything it outside the scope of JPA.  You should be looking at tagging the question at JDBC and if in java 1.6, might involve native DB specific SQL to find, but I'm not sure the reasoning - why do you need the schema names?  This is info that should be known upfront when you give the connection details to the application rather than rely on the application finding it - and it shouldn't matter to the application, should it?

Comment: agree with @Chris , JPA has nothing to do with backup, analysisi at 'logical level' can lead to false 'phisical interpretation' (U can ommit some 'formal'  objects), JPA has not 'snapshot' idea required for backup etc, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution for my problem at [Java Code Geek](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/sql/jdbc-databasemetadata-example/). I thought I have to use the schema to get all tables. This it not the case:

```
public static ArrayList getTablesMetadata() throws SQLException {
    String table[] = { "TABLE" };
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList tables = null;
    // receive the Type of the object in a String array.
    rs = metadata.getTables(null, null, null, table);
    tables = new ArrayList();
    while (rs.next()) {
        tables.add(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
    }
    return tables;
}
```

Comment: Your question should have been about what you were really after then, not the problem with your workaround.  Still not sure why you need table names at all, since your JPA application can read in entities and your application push that data where ever you need without knowing the underlying specifics at all.

Comment: Maybe. Yes, JPA got all entities and I could use them to backup the database. But I think at some point I would´ve to code the entities names statically like getClassForName("Entity").getAnnotation()' (not sure how it is done correctly, but I guess the Idea is correct). I know there exists a method 'getEntities()'. Of course I could parse them to a CSV format for a backup. In case of a recovery it will be complicated to build the entities and store them in the database, wouldn´t it?

Comment: If you are building a generic database recovery tool, I wouldn't use JPA at all and go straight to your database specific tools and documentation.  Otherwise, your application would know the entities (they are built in), and your application would know them the same way it would know what persistence unit or datasource to use, and so would be able to query for the data required to be backed up.  Dynamic lookups might be needed if you are backing up non-application data, and you then have to be careful as the datasource can be connected to a schema different from the one you may need to backup.